How was the average size of blk*.data chosen?
I notice that the Bitcoin database is stored sequentially in blk*.dat files, with an average size between 128 to 134MB. I would like to know how this average size is determined and if there are any tests that show this size is efficient.
The PR that introduced this limit, pull1677, suggests that this limit was chosen to reduce disk fragmentation of the files.
When I talk about efficiency, I'm referring to how this size can provide better read/write performance within the node.
Is there any performance test or theoretical basis that establishes this limit?

Of course, I could choose 256 MiB, which would result in less space. But, 128 MiB was chosen-why? It seems arbitrary. I read in on this forum that it's related to pruning, but I don't understand the reasoning behind it.
questions-50693

One point is that pruning is based on keeping a certain number of files, so smaller files give you finer control over the disk space used.  On the other hand, some filesystems have poor performance when there are a large number of files in a single directory, so that argues for a larger size.  This is a compromise, but probably was chosen arbitrarily rather than based on any theoretical model or empirical tests.

The comment about fragmentation isn't about the file size, but about the 16MB preallocation.

Reading through the code, it seems to be arbitrary. I would imagine there being some test for it, similar to what was conducted in the Google File System paper.

16MiB pre-allocation is the minimum of blk*dat?

Well, yes, but the point is that they grow the file only in 16 MB chunks (by writing 16 MB of zeros to it in quick succession, then overwriting those zeros with the actual block data as it arrives).  The hope is then that all 16 MB are contiguous on the disk.

Well, I suppose it's a matter of consistency. When the node is updated and receives new blocks, there can be a very large fork, expected to be up to 15 or 16 blocks. That's why this file remains unmodified until that uncertainty is practically eliminated.

I hope that explains the 16MiB. But now, what about the 128MiB?

AFAIK the blkNNNN.dat files remain unmodified, period.  They store blocks as they arrive, and keep them forever.  They don't delete them if they turn out to be orphaned.
